# accessing variables declared on other functions of a class c++

Tags: c++, linux

I have the following simple,beginners c++ code to do something with functions.can any one help me how to access variables declared in a function from another class, please.

### myclass.h

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class myclass
{
public:
   void function_1(string str1);
   void function_2(string str2);
   void function_3(string str_var1,string str_var2);
};
```

### myclass.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include"myclass.h"
using namespace std;

void myclass::function_1(string message1)
{
    string str_in_fun_1=message1;
}

// -------------------
void myclass::function_2(string message2)
{
    string str_in_fun_2=message2;
}

// ------------------   
void ::function_3(string str1,string str2)
{
    cout<<"we get:"<<str1<<"and"<<str2;
}
```

//main.cpp

```
#include"myclass.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    myclass in_myclass;
    in_myclass.function_1("this is my first function!");
    in_myclass.function_2("this is my second function!");
}
```

The problem is,can i access/use variables declared in function_1() and function_2() in this(below) way in function_3().

```
in_myclass.function_3(in_myclass.function_1.str_in_fun_1,in_myclass.function_2.str_in_fun_2) {
    return 0;
}
```

if not,help me please...

Comment: how does your code compile? you can access local variables defined on the method stack externally... can you post your complete source?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is this an exercise in the book you're learning from?  If so, please skip it.  Several C++ text books show that "Hey, you CAN pull stuff out of unallocated space in program memory" but frankly shouldn't.  It's an exercise in understanding how system memory is managed, and should never actually be used (as the variables aren't maintained anymore.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it the OP has some serious misconceptions about some basic language features.

Answer (score 1):

**NO.** It is not possible to access *method scoped* variable from outside of *that* method. It is also not *good design* if you need to access them. If the variables resembles *state* of class, then they should be class member and access directly/accesor methods. If they are just needed for computation in a method, they should be method local. Finally if none of these applies, make them *global* (although it is bad in *OO* perspective and may cause hard to find bug). Although if you need to keep them across several method call, make them `static`.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do that with global variables, preferably defined in .h file.
So if you want to use a variable a (type int) in function 1 and 2 do this:

```
int a; // add this to your myclass.h (outside class)
```

Then you can use 'a' in all functions/sub-programs that have `#include "myclass.h"`

Comment: declared in `.h` with `extern`. Defined in one of `.cpp`'s. You can't have multiple definitions.

Comment: yh my bad, I always mix declaration and definition but the principle is in place

Answer (score 0):

c++ allows you to access the variables initialized in one function to be accessed in other function with the data members of the respective class.
Redefine your class like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class myclass
{
public:
   String str1, str2;
public:
  function_1(string str1);
  function_2(string str2);
  function_3(string str_var1,string str_var2);
};
```